# Can't find reports in Team Foundation Server 2010

Tags: tfs

I have recently setup TFS 2010 and am trying to access the reporting feature.  TFS is installed on Windows Server 2008 R2 and I am accessing TFS using Visual Studio 2010.

From what I have seen on the web, I should have a reports option in Team Explorer or from the Team menu in Visual Studio.  I don't have this option at all.  I have seen MSDN articles saying the option may have a red cross next to it, but I don't see at all.

From the TFS Admin console, reporting seems to be setup.  All three options (Warehouse, Analysis Services and Report Server) have a green tick and say "Configured".

If I access the reports URL, I get a web interface but there are no out-of-the-box reports.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I found this article which shows how to setup new reports, but still can't figure out where the defaults have gone.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/how-to-create-reports-for-tfs-2010-test-results.aspx

Comment: Elsewhere I have read that reports are automatically created when you set up a new project and vary depending on the process template you choose.  I've created a few dummy projects using different process templates, still nothing.

Comment: install the Team Explorer client on the server where TFS is installed and run it to see if the reports folder is shown or not. If it's shown then you have a permission issue.

Comment: Done.  Still no reports option.  Do you know what the permissions are that I need?

Comment: See my answer, I can't paste picture here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that the default reports folder location had not been set. I only noticed by clicking through all the screens in desperation.

Open the TFS Admin Console, go to Application Tier > Team Project Collections.  Then in the Reports Folder tab at the bottom make sure you have set a value.  I just used the default example which was /TfsReports/DefaultCollection.

Comment: I should also add you need to then re-create your Team Project - this will set up the reports for it

Comment: The two upvoted answers comprise the complete list of things to check for this issue.

Comment: Hi @rf_wilson, I upgraded from 2013 update 4 to 2017 update 3 and not able to see the "Reports folder tab" you are talking about. Only tabs available for me are: General, status and Team Projects. 

Please note that I configured SSRS(SQL 2016 U 1) after TFS upgrade and not during the upgrade.

Comment: It appeared after TFS server restart :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't see the folder "Reports" in this view?

[image]

Do you have a screen like this?

[image]

Comment: No, I don't see Documents either for that matter

Comment: Ok, so you did the setup, right? You installed SQL server with the same account you installed TFS? After TFS was installed what kind of configuration did you choose? (Basic, Standard, Custom)

Comment: TFS is using an AD account which has local admin rights, SQL server is the same as far as I know. I chose a custom install of TFS.

Comment: I just figured it out... see my answer